# SharePoint (MOSS 2007) Adding "This Folder" option to Out-of-box Search dropdown

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We want to add "This Folder" scope to the search dropdown in a document librady. By default, This Site and This List appear in it. One way would be to add scope, but then every time a folder is created, scope would have to be added. Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom scope for each folder.

If you look at the URL used for searching when you use "This site" and "This List", you'll notice that what is added it the Query Parameter '&u=Url of site/list' you can just use this with Url of folder

Comment: Thanks Per. That is right, the URL is embedded in querystring. The question is how do I get the "This Folder" option and make it carry the full path upto the folder level.